# How to query data from collectionGroups in Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

For an app I'm building in Flutter I'm trying to retrieve a list of reserved timeslots by the logged in user across different days from Firestore. I get to a point where I can retrieve the reserved timeslots on a given day (by hardcoding the day and passing it on to a futurebuilder), but when I try to retrieve data from a collectionGroup the listview stays empty (snapshot doesn't have data). Now, as a Flutter beginner I find understanding how to handle collectionGroup queries quite difficult and therefore any help would be appreciated!

For a quick overview of how my database is structured I have included 2 pictures on github:

Picture 1: https://github.com/winckles/rooster/blob/master/Schermafbeelding%202019-11-10%20om%2020.08.20.png?raw=true

Picture 2: https://github.com/winckles/rooster/blob/master/Schermafbeelding%202019-11-10%20om%2020.08.43.png?raw=true

Below I have included my futurebuilder and listview builder

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TimesTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimesTestState createState() => _TimesTestState();
}

class _TimesTestState extends State<TimesTest> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: MyFutureBuilder(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyFutureBuilder extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: MyTimes().getMyTimes('${loggedInUser.email}'),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 7.0,
                    vertical: 3.0,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Container(
                          child: ListTile(
                            onTap: () {},
                            title: Text(
                              user.data['hour'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[900],
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              user.data['reserved'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[900],
                              ),
                            ),
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.access_time,
                              color: Colors.grey[900],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              });
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            !snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('No times found'),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Text('Something else is wrong'),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I get the data from firestore.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class MyTimes {
  Future getMyTimes(String reserved) async {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('hours')
        .where('reserved', isEqualTo: reserved)
        .getDocuments();
  }
}
```

I have created an index with collection id 'hours' and with collection range 'collectionGroup', my security rules right now are the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }

    match /{path=**}/hours/{document}{
    allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I've spend hours and hours trying to find this out already, so really anything useful would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem; First my snapshot could retrieve ALL the data from 'hours' When I removed the `.where('reserved', isEqualTo: reserved)`, but it didn't work when I included it, so the code worked but only the query didn't. This was due to the index settings of my Firestore database. I read the documentation on indexes for Firestore here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview?authuser=0#automatic_indexing

After I realized I had only made a composite index while I didn't look at the **single-field index exemptions**. I added two exemptions:

One for the field 'hour' in collectionGroup 'hours' while checking the boxes ascending and descending and one for the field 'reserved' in collectionGroup 'hours' while checking the boxes ascending and descending again. Now it does work!

Answer (score 2):

> After I realized I had only made a composite index while I didn't look at the single-field index exemptions

If you are looking for a way of doing this using `firebase cli` you can do it in this way:

1. create a file called `firestore.indexes.json`

```
{
  "indexes": [],
  "fieldOverrides": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "your_sub_collection",
      "fieldPath": "the_field",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "order": "ASCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "DESCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "arrayConfig": "CONTAINS",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "ASCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION_GROUP"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In this way, you are preserving the default for the collection scope and enabling the `ASCENDING` one for the collection group scope instead.

1. In your `firebase.json`:

```
  "firestore": {
    "indexes": "indexes/firestore.indexes.json"
  },
```

3. run `firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes`

This will do the job and finally, your `collectionGroup` query will work as expected.

Hope it helps to save some time.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are not using a collectionGroup query. You need to do something like `Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('hours').where('reserved', isEqualTo: '').getDocuments();` for non-reserved slots.

So, what do you store in your 002 document when that slot ís reserved? And why don't you use an explicit type like a boolean for the status? That makes it easier too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've updated my code to what you suggested however, now my snapshot retrieves no data (I get 'No times found').
In document 002 I store the next timeslot so 'hour: 09:00-10:00' and again 'reserved: " " '. I've named them to get them in order. When the logged in user reserves a timeslot the reserved field is updated to 'reserved: logged in users email'. 
I understand the boolean thing, but I would like to show other users who reserved the timeslot if it's not free. And would I then not have a problem with displaying the reserved times by the logged in user?